# Python caching file reads? File reads are faster on second execution

Tags: python, file, caching, io

I wrote a simple caching script that searches through a directory for certain files, hashes that directory and then reads and processes the files found in that directory in a loop. It then writes the hash plus whatever data I was able to pull to a file.

On the first execution it takes about twenty seconds which is expected as there are lots of big files to regex match line by line. However, on subsequent executions, it runs MUCH faster, around 4 seconds. This seems to persist even if I start a new instance of the python interpreter or close out my IDE (Spyder) entirely.

What's interesting though is that if I run the script on a different folder, it takes about 20 seconds again, then back to 4 seconds every time after. Also interesting, is that running it with Python 3 on those same two folders also takes 20 seconds the first time, then again back to 4 seconds every time after. If I rename the folder, it only takes 4 seconds on the first run. So far I haven't been able to recreate the 20 second runtime at all.

It seems to me that Python or the OS must be internally caching the file reads (just an educated guess as I think the open() calls are the most expensive).

I'm not using anything fancy here btw, just pythons built-in open() and looping through the lines, the re module and a very minimal hash module that can be found [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=checksumdir%20python).

Here's one of the functions that opens and processes these files in a loop (the others are virtually the same, just searching in different paths)

```
def createGlobalDataDictionary(self, path):
    dict1 = {}        
    dict2 = {}
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    self.filelist[path] = hashfunc.dirhash(path, 'sha1')
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if i.endswith(".m"):
            if re.match('.*foo.*', i):
                openi = open(os.path.join(path, i), "r")
                for line in openi:
                    if re.match('.*bar.*', line):
                        key = line.split('.')[0]
                        value = line.partition('\'')[-1].rpartition('\'')[0]
                        dict1[key] = value
                openi.close()

            elif re.match('.*baz.*', i):
                openi = open(os.path.join(path, i), "r")
                for line in openi:
                    if re.match(".*qux.*", line):
                        key = line.split('.')[0]
                        value = line.partition('\'')[-1].rpartition('\'')[0]
                        dict2[key] = value
                openi.close()

    return (dict1, dict2)
```

I'm using WinPython 32-Bit 2.7.6.3 and WinPython 64-Bit 3.4.2.4

I've been trying to figure out what's causing this behavior all day and I'm pretty stumped so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The OS certainly has a caching layer under the filesystem.

Comment: The caching could be done in the OS level. Linux and new versions of Windows (iirc Vista onwards) by default will cache the most recently opened files in RAM.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Alright, thanks. Does this mean my caching script is basically useless lol...?  I guess it still saves about 1 second but I was more concerned about 20 seconds vs 4 seconds, rather than 3 vs 4. At any rate, this leads me to another question which is, is caching anything in Python ever worth it? Under what circumstances _should_ I cache something? Just so I don't make the mistake of wasting time writing something that only provides marginal performance gains.